# How to group data by rows?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am finding difficulty grouping rows by using identifiers. I have 3 columns `Data`, `ID`, and `Location`. I am trying to use queries to somehow search up the location and ID number so data would show up for one particular data point. The issue is, my data is in rows instead of columns: My table is shown below:

```
    Data                    ID  Location

    CONTINGENCY 'AA:P1_AA'   1     X
     DISCONNECT BUS 1        
     DISCONNECT BUS 2        
     DISCONNECT BUS 3        
     DISCONNECT BUS 4        
     DISCONNECT BUS 5        
     DISCONNECT BUS 6        
     DISCONNECT BUS 7        
    END      
    CONTINGENCY 'AB:P1_AB'   2     X
     DISCONNECT BUS 8        
     DISCONNECT BUS 9        
     DISCONNECT BUS 10           
    END      
    CONTINGENCY 'AC:P1_AC'   3     X
     DISCONNECT BUS 11       
     DISCONNECT BUS 12       
     DISCONNECT BUS 13       
    END
```

I tried use two queries where I search up the ID and Location and some data would show up in front of me. The issue is when I search it, only one line of data pops up. 
For example:
`[Please enter Location:]` Lets say I type in X
`[Please enter ID #:]` Lets say I pick 1

The output from access when running Query would be:
`CONTINGENCY 'AB:P1_AB'`

My desired output is

```
CONTINGENCY 'AB:P1_AB'      
 DISCONNECT BUS 8        
 DISCONNECT BUS 9        
 DISCONNECT BUS 10           
END
```

I do realize I can just type in 1's and X's for all those lines of data but it would be inefficient. Is there some way where I can group all those lines of code together when I do search queries.

````
FROM Sheet2
WHERE (((Sheet2.Location)=[Please enter Location:]) AND ((Sheet2.ID)=[Please enter ID #:]));```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encountering issues because your data does not follow basic [database normalisation rules](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/283878/description-of-the-database-normalization-basics) - it has no structure and is merely presented in a list as you might use in Excel.

Consider that MS Access works with **unordered datasets**, and therefore **you cannot rely on the order of records output by a query unless an `order by` clause is specified.**

For your dataset, this means that there is nothing relating the `DISCONNECT BUS 1` record to the `CONTINGENCY 'AA:P1_AA'` record.

As a start, I would suggest splitting your data into two separate tables: the first might contain the `'header'` information, such as:

```
+---------+------------------------+----------+
| ID (PK) |          Data          | Location |
+---------+------------------------+----------+
|       1 | CONTINGENCY 'AA:P1_AA' | X        |
|       2 | CONTINGENCY 'AB:P1_AB' | X        |
|       3 | CONTINGENCY 'AC:P1_AC' | X        |
+---------+------------------------+----------+
```

The second (call it `'detail'`) would have the contents of each `'header'` record, linked on the primary key in the `'header'` table, e.g.:

```
+---------+----------+-------------------+
| ID (PK) | HID (FK) |       Data        |
+---------+----------+-------------------+
|       1 |        1 | DISCONNECT BUS 1  |
|       2 |        1 | DISCONNECT BUS 2  |
|       3 |        1 | DISCONNECT BUS 3  |
|       4 |        1 | DISCONNECT BUS 4  |
|       5 |        1 | DISCONNECT BUS 5  |
|       6 |        1 | DISCONNECT BUS 6  |
|       7 |        1 | DISCONNECT BUS 7  |
|       8 |        2 | DISCONNECT BUS 8  |
|       9 |        2 | DISCONNECT BUS 9  |
|      10 |        2 | DISCONNECT BUS 10 |
|      11 |        3 | DISCONNECT BUS 11 |
|      12 |        3 | DISCONNECT BUS 12 |
|      13 |        3 | DISCONNECT BUS 13 |
+---------+----------+-------------------+
```

Here, `FK` stands for [Foreign Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key); `PK` stands for [Primary Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key). The foreign key in my proposed `'detail'` table contains the value of the ID primary key field in the `'header'` table.

That way, you can easily create a query with obtains the required results, e.g.:

```sql
select header.data, detail.data
from header inner join detail on header.id = detail.hid
where header.id = [Please enter an ID:] and header.location = [Please enter a location:]
```

Comment: what is `FK` in `HID (FK)` and how do you assign it?  Thanks for help by the way

Comment: `FK` stands for [Foreign Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key); `PK` stands for [Primary Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key). The foreign key in my proposed 'detail' table contains the value of the `ID` primary key field in the 'header' table.